# Columns on the Entry index page giving errors

Tags: entrymodel

For some reason whenever I add a custom column to a section's entry list I'm getting errors and no values.

If I add Entry Type to the column list, for example, it's saying:

```
Unknown class: Craft\EntryTypeModel
```

And links are saying:

```
Unknown class: Twig_Markup
```

[image: screenshot of errors]

I'm a little dumbfounded?  I tried removing and re-adding them and still no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Weird... I'd guess you're missing some `craft/app` files.  Can you try replacing your existing `craft/app` folder with a fresh one downloaded from https://craftcms.com?

Comment: Yea I tried that too, no luck?

Comment: Can you verify `craft/app/models/EntryTypeModel.php` exists and its permissions are such that PHP can read it?

Comment: If all that checks out, can you look in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` find the error and edit the original question to include the full stack trace for it?

Comment: Ugh, im an idiot i had an old Plugin installed "DashCols" that was what was causing it of course.  Sorry!

Comment: Hah... no worries!  Mind adding that as the official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out it was an issue with an older plugin, DashCols. As soon as I disabled it things worked fine.

Unsurprising in hindsight!